# SQL Server : removing duplicate column while joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables with one column is common on all tables. Is there a way to create a view where I can join all tables by same column where I see the common column only once.

Let's say I have table1

```
Cust ID | Order ID | Product_Name
```

Table2

```
Cust_ID | Cust_Name | Cust_Address
```

Table3

```
Cust_ID | Cust_Acc | Acc_Type
```

Table4

```
Cust_ID | Contact_Phone | Cust_Total_Ord
```

Here is the code I use to join tables;

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Cust_ID = table2.Cust_ID
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.Cust_ID = table3.Cust_ID
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.Cust_ID = table4.Cust_ID
```

I get all tables joined by I see `Cust_ID` from each table as below;

```
Cust ID| Order ID|Product_Name| Cust_ID| Cust_Name|Cust_Address| Cust_ID| Cust_Acc| Acc_Type|Cust_ID|Contact_Phone|Cust_Total_Ord
```

Is there a way to remove duplicate `Cust_ID` columns or do I need to write each column name in the `SELECT`? I have more than 50 columns in total so will be difficult to write all.

Sorry if it is a really dumb question, I have checked previous similar questions but couldn't figure out and thanks for help.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 16):

you have common columns on all tables so could use `using(common_column)` to remove duplicated columns.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 using(Cust_ID)
LEFT JOIN table3 using(Cust_ID)
LEFT JOIN table4 using(Cust_ID)
```

I hop that useful.

Comment: Most useful answer. I really appreciate how this approach helps reduce the headache of selecting the multiple column names explicitly from every table. Can you do a small favor? Please include the reference link which describer `using()` clause in detail.

Comment: hi, so sorry for late. https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljusing.html this id the oracle reference which I used.

Comment: SQL Server (as in the original question) doesn't support the USING clause

Answer (score 10):

you need to select columns from three tables first and then make inner join like below

```
select 
  t1.cust_id, t1.col1, t1.col2, 
  t2.col1_table2, t2.col2_table2, 
  t3.col1_table3, t3.col2_table3
from
 table1 t1 
inner join
 table2 t2 on t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
join table3 t3 on t1.cust_id = t3.cust_id
```

Result as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it is helpful but I have around 40 different columns in my real data that's why I was trying to find out if there is an easier way, still thanks a lot for taking time and creating this sample code.

Comment: Sounds like you just don't want a lot of typiing - you could use a query builder tool like the one in SSMS to build the query and thn copy and paste. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot easily do what you want in SQL Server.  In other databases, you can use the `using` clause.

One thing you can do is select the columns explicitly from all but the first table:

```
SELECT t1.*, . . .
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.Cust_ID = t2.Cust_ID LEFT JOIN
     table3
     ON t1.Cust_ID = table3.Cust_ID LEFT JOIN
     table4
     ON t1.Cust_ID = table4.Cust_ID;
```

Perhaps more important than the column issue, I changed the join conditions.  You are using `LEFT JOIN`, so the first table is the "driving" table.  When you say `t2.Cust_ID = t3.Cust_Id`, this returns true *only when there was a match to `table2`*.  In general, you want to use the columns from `table1`, because it is the first one in the chain of `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will update that in my query